# Unable to read kubernetes property

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

Im working on a policy that dictates that a `kaniko` image must always run on a nodePool `kaniko-nodepool`.

If a kaniko image is deployed anywhere else, it will be a violation. Im using a combination of container image and nodeSelector to enforce the policy

My policy works well https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/GOJNyAF5TW .

Change `input.review.object.spec.nodeSelector.pool` to cause the violation

The only issue remaining is that what if the pod has no nodeSelector and the image being deployed is kaniko, a violation should occur too.

So I added

```
not input.review.object.spec.nodeSelector
```

meaning if there is no nodeSelector, that should be true for a violation. Once I remove the whole nodeSelector part, it does not cause a violation.

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/AuhepivPHN

Clicking on coverage shows that none of the lines are being processed.

Is there something im missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few combos myself..
Based on the documentation [here](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#objects),
`not obj.foo.bar.baz` checks if paths `foo.bar.baz`, or `foo.bar` or `foo` does not exist.
In your case, `input.review.object.spec` will always exist .. so, the `not input.review.object.spec.nodeSelector` might not be the best option.
What I tried was [here](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/Gu6cEHOKe5)
i.e. throw a violation if

1. pool is wrong OR
2. nodeSelector is missing ..

Let me know if this helps.